# make div larger than window?

Tags: html, css

This probably is a stupid question and the answer is probably no but.. has anyone ever figured out a way to make a div "overflow" off of the window of a browser? Particularly on Chrome? Basically I've got a div which is a list which is overlayed on top of a webpage. I'd like the list not to be cut off by the window (assuming the window isn't maximized)

Ideally I'd like the window to remain the same size but the list continue past where the window ends. This is the ideal affect I'm looking for However, if anyone has a next best thing solution that will also be of great help!

Comment: So you want the window to expand to the size of the list?

Comment: Can you go into more detail? Do you want the list to move when the browser window gets smaller than the width of the website but stays put when the expanded larger than the width of the website?

Comment: It's impossible to `"make a div "overflow" off of the window of a browser"`. Just in case there was any doubt.

Comment: We're gonna need a drawing to understand this question :). As far as I know, when a div's content is big enough, a div always outgrows the window size.  Automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either do:

```
width: 150%;
```

or

```
width: 2000px;
```

or however wide it needs to be.

**Edit:**  Oh - you don't mean render actually wider than the browser? (as opposed to scrolling). If so then the answer is most definitely No.

Comment: It's actually the height and the list may or may not be that large, so I'd want to do max-height right?

Comment: @Skizit: max-height will ensure the div is no higher than that height. For scroll properties, see the css value "overflow"

Answer (score 3):

Browser is an application that parses, interprets html and finally shows the output. There is no way to make div flow out of the browser, thats pretty impossible as per my knowledge. Whats the problem in providing div with a horizontal and/or vertical scroll bar when required.